# Elasticsearch Context Suggester geo context - boost without filtering?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm creating a completion suggester with a geo context (Elastic 5.x).

```
 mapping...
        "suggest": {
          "type": "completion",
          ...
          "contexts": [
          {
            "name": "geoloc",
            "type": "geo",
            "precision": 3,
            "path": "geolocation"
          }
        ]
```

When I query this, I'd like to have it *not* filter by the geo context, only boost results that are within the geohash.  It works great to filter by a single geohash, or filter by a lower precision, and then boost a higher precision within that original filter like this:

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
  "suggest": {
      ...
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest",
        "size": "10",
        "contexts": {
          "geoloc": [
            {
              "lat": 44.8214564,
              "lon": -93.475399,
              "precision": 1
            },
            {
              "lat": 44.8214564,
              "lon": -93.475399,
              "boost": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      }
  }
}
```

However, I can't get it to only boost on a single geo context without filtering. 
 When I submit the following query, it filters *and* boosts:

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
  "suggest": {
      ...
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest",
        "size": "10",
        "contexts": {
          "geoloc": [
            {
              "lat": 44.8214564,
              "lon": -93.475399,
              "boost": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do just not supported, or am I missing something?

Thanks!
Jason

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I ended up using edge ngrams instead of completion suggesters. You have much more flexibility to filter/boost when using the normal "query" vs contexts within a "suggest".

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this issue as well.

The solution I came up with through trial and error was to use the category context to filter first to all my documents. Say you had added a category to your documents named "all" you could do this:

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
  "suggest": {
      ...
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest",
        "size": "10",
        "contexts": {
          "category": ["all"],
          "geoloc": [
            {
              "lat": 44.8214564,
              "lon": -93.475399,
              "precision": 2,
              "boost": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      }
  }
}
```

When this is done, it seems to be selecting everything with the "all" category and then boosts the ones within the precision level specified to the top.

Using Elastic 6.*